# Set Db2 statement terminator using C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I want to create stored procedures in Db2 using C#.

My script looks something like this:

```
create procedure test 
P1: begin 
statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
end P1ß
```

To execute the procedures, I use the `DB2Command.ExeCuteNonQuery()` function.

The problem is that `;` is used as a terminator, but I need a custom terminator.
Attempting to set the terminator with `--#SET TERMINATOR ß` is only recognized as a comment.

Is there another way to set the terminator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom terminator. Since you can only issue a single statement at a time using the OLE DB interface, the entire string you send is treated as a statement (in your case -- `create procedure test ... end p1`), and the presence of `;`s inside it does not matter.